# Change default timestamp offset on data load

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I've got a number of tables that I'm loading in from a SQL server. The timestamp in SQL server is stored like 2003-11-24T09:02:32 I get these as parquet files in our raw storage location and pick them up in Databricks. When I load the data in databricks, the dataframe/spark assumes UTC or +0000 on the timestamp like 2003-11-24T09:02:32+0000 the time and date is the same as what's in SQL server however the offset is incorrect

I've tried various methods like the below code to set the JVM timezone to my local timezone but when viewing the data it seems to just subtract the offset from the timestamp and add it to the offset part like 2003-11-24T09:02:32+0000 -> 2003-11-23T20:02:32+1300 (NZ has a +13 offset in winter)

```
`spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession \
.Builder()\
.appName('test') \
.master('local') \
.config('spark.driver.extraJavaOptions', '-Duser.timezone=Pacific/Auckland') \
.config('spark.executor.extraJavaOptions', '-Duser.timezone=Pacific/Auckland') \
.config('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'Pacific/Auckland') \
.getOrCreate()`
```

I understand that in Parquet these are stored as UNIX time and aren't timezone aware, however are there any settings that I can set in spark that would implicitly convert/assume the timestamp from 2003-11-24T09:02:32+0000 to 2003-11-24T09:02:32+1300 I know this can be done with transformations however I'm trying to avoid doing transformations for every timestamp on 100's tables

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68956623/how-apply-a-different-timezone-to-a-timestamp-in-pyspark   Does this help `spark.conf.set('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC')` ?

Comment: @user238607 yes, I have tried this. It only changes how the timestamp gets represented eg `1-1-2022T15:00:00+0000` changes to `1-1-2022T02:00:00+1300`, my problem is my time is local in my source files not utc but when read in spark it assumes the time is utc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a way to solve my problem without applying a transformation (emailed the spark user mailing list for confirmation)

The most succinct way I could come up with was the below, where `new_df` is a table being read that contains the same data as `df`

```
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession \
.Builder()\
.appName('test') \
.master('local') \
.config('spark.driver.extraJavaOptions', '-Duser.timezone=Pacific/Auckland') \
.config('spark.executor.extraJavaOptions', '-Duser.timezone=Pacific/Auckland') \
.config('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'Pacific/Auckland') \
.getOrCreate()

timestamp_columns = [column[0] for column in df.dtypes if column[1] == 'timestamp']
new_df = spark.read.table("my_table")
for column_name in timestamp_columns:
    new_df = new_df.withColumn(column_name, to_utc_timestamp(col(column_name), 'Pacific/Auckland'))
```